# WAS API to change AD password Java

Tags: java, active-directory, websphere, websphere-6.1

I am using Container based authentication to authenticate my Web Application against Windows 2003 Active Directory. I am using WAS 6.1 as application server. Now there is a new requirement to change the password from the Web application itself. I would like to know if I can make use of any WAS API for this purpose.